# Creating a Sequence of numbers in dynamically generated images using database values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a web app that generates barcodes. It creates the barcodes by the amount entered by the user, then generates the code using the amount, a date value, and values in a checkboxlist. The data entered by the user is then sent to a database using a stored procedure. The date values and amount values in the corresponding table are reset every 24 hours, but if the user enters the values it increases, in a sequence throughout the day. What I'm trying to figure out is, if I can implement that sequence in my images that I am generating. I've attempted to use an SQL Reader but I don't know how to implement it correctly since it's in the foreach and for loop. The foreach takes the selected values in the checkbox list which then in the for loop creates the amount desired starting from the amount entered.

For example

```
1st. Attempt

[X] AB
[] BC
[] CD
[] DE

Please Enter Amount [   4]
Please Enter Date   [08/24/2016]

Barcodes:
AB08241601   AB08241602   AB08241603  AB08241604

2nd. Attempt

[X] AB
[] BC
[] CD
[] DE

Please Enter Amount [   3]
Please Enter Date   [08/24/2016]

Barcodes:
AB08241605  AB08241606   AB08241607
```

Here is the code that works

```
protected void Generate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

       CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyle style = DateTimeStyle.None;
       DateTime dt;
       DateTime.TryParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddyyyy", provider, style out dt);
       int i = Int32.Parse(amount.Text);

       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       cmd.Connection = conn;


      foreach(List item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
      {    
         for(int n = 1; n <= i; n++) 
         {

         if (item.Selected)
         {

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            string barcode_label = item.Text + "QTY:___________"

           //When image generates, it will show 1 to user input amount                 
           string barode_data = item.Value + datepicker.Text + n.ToSTring("D2");

           Bitmap dynImage = DrawBarcode(barcode_data, barcode_label)

           MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

           dynImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

           byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

           Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

           img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

           panel1.Controls.Add(img);

           double spacing;

           double mg = 5;

           spacing = img.Width.Value + mg;

       }

    } 

 }


       foreach(ListItem item2 in CheckBoxList1.Items)
       {

           if(item2.Selected)
           {

             //handling parameters in loop.

             cmd.Parameters["@SeqNum"].Value = amount.Text;
             cmd.Parameters["@SeqDate"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
             cmd.Parameters["@Account_ID"].item2.Value;
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                 try
                 {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }

                   catch (SqlException ex)
                   {
                     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                   }

                  finally
                  {
                     conn.Close();
                  }


             }

       }

}
```

SQL Code

```
 CREATE TABLE AccountTable
 (
     RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
     AccountID varchar(2),
     AccountName varchar(50),
     SeqNum int,
     SeqDate datetime
 )  

  CREATE PROCEDURE [ACCOUNTTABLE_UPDATE]
  (
    @SeqNum int,
    @SeqDate datetime,
    @Account_ID varchar(2)
  )

AS 
 SET NOCOUNT ON
  BEGIN
   UPDATE AccountTable
     SET SeqNum = SeqNum + @SeqNum, SeqDate = @SeqDate
     WHERE AccountID = @AccountID
  END
```

SqlDataReader() Attempt

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SeqNum FROM AccountTable;";

 conn.Open();
 SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 foreach(List item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
 {    
     for(int n = 1; n <= i; n++) 
     {

     if (item.Selected)
     {
       if(sdr.Read())
       {

        n = (int)sdr["SeqNum"];
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        string barcode_label = item.Text + "QTY:___________"

       //When image generates, it will show 1 to user input amount                 
       string barode_data = item.Value + datepicker.Text + n.ToSTring("D2");

       Bitmap dynImage = DrawBarcode(barcode_data, barcode_label)

       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

       dynImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

       byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

       Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

       img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

       panel1.Controls.Add(img);

       double spacing;

       double mg = 5;

       spacing = img.Width.Value + mg;

     }

    }

  } 

}
```

while the database updates correctly it just displays the value found in the    database and generates the first barcode with the database value and all other barcodes with with the value of 0. The amount of barcodes displayed corresponds to the Length of total items in my checkbox list. For an example below, if the Data for the checkbox selected = 4, if I run my code, the value in my database correctly changes to 6, but I get the results below

```
[X] AB
[] BC
[] CD
[] DE

  Please Enter Amount [   2]
  Please Enter Date   [08/24/2016]

  Barcodes:
  AB08241604  AB08241600   AB08241600  AB08241600
```

I don't know how to execute the reader with the items selected in the foreach loop since they are already being used to generate the barcodes themselves.